# Can I space a gnuplot grid differently than tics?

Tags: graph, gnuplot

How can I add an X grid with different spacing than the tics?  My plot is a histogram showing # of patents (of a certain type) granted per year, and the year range is large (1807-1971).  I'd like to tic/label each year but only add X grid lines every decade (and also use a different color for the matching decade labels).

I've been searching for an answer and trying things for hours and getting nowhere.  Are either of these possible?

My current plot (with no X grid) looks like:

[image: gnuplot histogram]

And the script is:

```
set style data histograms
set style histogram gap 1
set style fill solid
set title "Number of Prism Glass Patents Granted" font "fixed, 24" offset 0,-0.9
set xlabel "Year" font "fixed,18" offset 0,0.8
set nokey
set xtics out nomirror rotate font "fixed, 8" offset 0,0.4
set grid y
plot 'frequency.dat' using 2:xtic(1) linecolor 'blue'
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume your data consists out of two columns: Year and number of patents.
Why do you use `xitc(1)`, is it necessary to label every single year?
What about using minor and major xtics? I would use plotstyle `with boxes`.

**Code:**

```
### major and minor xtics
reset session

# generate some random data
set print $Data
    do for [i=1807:1971] {
        print sprintf("%d %d", i, int(rand(0)*100))
    }
set print

set xlabel "Year"
set xtics out nomirror
unset x2tics
set xtics 10
set mxtics 10
set grid ytics
set grid xtics
set boxwidth 0.5
plot $Data u 1:2 with boxes fill solid 1.0 lc rgb "blue" notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Another version with grid every 10 years and label with different color. Labels are only shown  when number of patents>0. Instead of using `xtics` it is done by plotting `with labels`.

**Code:**

```
### major and minor xtics
reset session

set term pngcairo size 1600,360
set output "tbGrid.png"

xmin = 1807
xmax = 1971

# generate some random data
set print $Data
    do for [i=xmin:xmax] {
        print sprintf("%d %d", i, int(rand(0)+0.4)*(int(rand(0)*100)))
    }
set print

set xlabel "Year" offset 0,-1.5
set xrange[xmin-1:xmax+1]
set xtics 10 format "" out nomirror

set mxtics 10
set bmargin 5
set grid ytics 
set grid xtics
set boxwidth 0.5

myTic(n,p) = p==0 ? "" : sprintf("%d",n)
myColor(n) = int(n)%10==0 ? 0xff0000 : 0x000000

plot $Data u 1:2 with boxes fill solid 1.0 lc rgb "blue" notitle, \
    '' u 1:(0):(myTic($1,$2)):(myColor($1)) with labels \
    tc rgb var rotate offset 0,-1.5 font ",8" notitle
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yes the data is two columns, year and count.  I want to label every year so that the peaks and early single-patent years can be read directly (they are significant), though if I could omit the labels from the zero-count years I might.  Histogram style was the obvious choice since a histogram is what I want, but when I plot using 2:xtic(1) then xtics start/incr/end are ignored, as is mxtics, and the grid always matches the xtics (_i.e._ yearly).

Answer (score 2):

The grid for each axis is generated from the tics for that same axis, so yes they always match.  However if your plot uses only the x1 axis, you could define the range and tics for the x2 axis also and turn on the grid only for x2 and not for x1.

Recent gnuplot versions have a command `set link x2` that ensures the x1 and x2 axes agree on the range and scale.  If your version does not support this you can still set them to match explicitly:

```
set xrange [min:max]
set x2range [min:max]

set xtics <whatever>        # these will label the actual plot
set x2tics <something else> # these will be used only for grid lines
set x2tics scale 0.0 format ""  # show no x2 tics or labels on the plot

set grid x2 nox
plot ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both-- here's my final plot:

[image]

...and its script:

```
# histogram of # of prism glass patents granted per year
###
set term png size 1800,600

xmin = 1807
xmax = 1971

set title sprintf("Prism Glass Patents Granted %d-%d", xmin, xmax) \
    font "fixed, 24" offset 0,-0.5

set xlabel "Year" font "fixed,24" offset 0,-2

# x tic for each year
set xrange [xmin-1:xmax+1]
set xtics 1 out nomirror format ""

# x2 tic and gridline for each decade
set x2tics 1800,10,1970
set x2tics out font "fixed, 12" offset 0,-0.6
set grid x2 nox

set grid y              # y axis is count

set boxwidth 0.5
set bmargin 5
set nokey

myTic(y,n) = n==0 ? "" : sprintf("%d",y)   # only label year if count>0
myColor(y) = y==1897 ? 0x0000FF : 0x000000 # highlight 1897 (biggest year)

plot 'frequency.dat' using 1:2 with boxes fill solid lc rgb "blue", \
        '' using 1:(0):(myTic($1,$2)):(myColor($1)) with labels \
        tc rgb var rotate offset 0.1,-1.2 font "fixed,8"
```